# Click-lock Alternative?

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I was wondering if there was an alternative to click-lock for mac? I can't use drag lock because of limited hand movement. I need something where I can move the cursor to where I want to drag, hold down the left or right mouse button for a number of seconds, be able to release, and then it will be in infinite drag until I click again to release the drag (similar to how click-lock is on Windows). I tried to use btt, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What was your issue with BTT?

Comment: Also, is the the long-click the only option for you? Could it also be another trigger like pressing left and right button simultaneously?

Answer (score 7):

There is a built-in equivalent for *trackpads*, called dragging, which you find in System Preferences > Accessibility > Trackpad Options:

[image]

In case this is not sufficient for you or you need to use a mouse, have a look at the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/303424/215109). Currently the following third-party apps are being mentioned:

- [Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/) (free) is a popular choice for gestures and automation. It offers a feature called "Grab Scroll".
- [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (free) a similar and popular tool.
- [Smooze](https://smooze.co) (commercial)
- [Smart Scroll](http://marcmoini.com/sx_en.html) (commercial)

[Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai) (commercial) is my personal favourite as it allows so much more, such as another Windows-inspired feature, called window snapping, etc. The procedure here would be as follows:

1. Open BTT preferences
2. Select Input device, i.e. Mouse
3. Select Trigger. The one you mention (i.e. long press) currently seems not to be available. (*I suggest you make a feature request on [their forum](https://community.folivora.ai). The developer is usually very open to such requests.*) Instead you could do e.g. middle-click.
4. Select action. Go to Window Resize & Move > Start/Stop Moving or search.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete solution because it doesn't answer the question as asked.

I'm hoping someone can find a solution that may involve the trackpad/gestures control panel, but I don't have any machine with one so I can't test.

In the meantime, if you have an extended keyboard, then Mouse Keys might go some way towards, if not exactly as asked, then some way towards achieving a similar result.

In System Prefs > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad there is Mouse Keys [in the Options you can set it to toggle on/off by tapping Opt 5 times]
It enables the 10-key NumPad on an extended keyboard to be used to drive the mouse cursor. 123, 46, 789 act as directional navigators. 5 is the click.
I had hoped that with Mouse Keys on, it would allow you to press 5 & then drag the actual mouse to carry out the task. Unfortunately it won't do that, they seem to partially ignore each other. Any 'real' mouse seems to act independently, so 5 will click but dragging the mouse won't 'carry' that click.

However, holding 5 & using the direction keys, the click does 'hold', so click & hold a title bar, for instance, then the keys will 'carry' the window until you release 5.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for me because in order for mouse keys to work, you have to have an external keyboard and I can't use an external keyboard because of my physical disability :-(